# Swap(): свойство или индексатор не могут передаваться как параметр out или ref

Tags: c#, индексы, swap, ref

Альтернативный заголовок: Как правильно сделать `Swap(Array[i],Array[j])`?

Есть универсальный метод Swap

```cs
        public static void swap<T>(ref T a, ref T b)
        {
            T c = a;
            a = b;
            b = c;
        }
```

И я пытаюсь использовать его так:

```cs
List<MyClass> Parent0;
//...
for (int p = 0; p < 2; p++)
{
    while (Mutated[p].Count>1) 
    {
        swap(ref Parent0[Mutated[p].Pop()], ref Parent0[Mutated[p].Pop()]); //Pop() возвращает int
    }
}
//...
```

Но компилятор выдаёт ошибку. Как сделать Swap(a,b) в таком случае? `Mutated[p].Pop()` разный при каждом вызове, поэтому я не могу использовать `(а,b) = (b,а)`, не объявляя дополнительных переменных (да и такая запись сильно удлиняет код и делает его менее понятным, чем `Swap(a,b)`)

Comment: а что с чем оно должно поменять местами?

Comment: оно должно поменять местами первый параметр и второй (`Swap (a,b)` – поменять местами a и b). Напомню, что `Mutated[p].Pop()` выдаёт разное значение при каждом вызове, поэтому `Parent0[Mutated[p].Pop()]` != `Parent0[Mutated[p].Pop()]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все верно, вы не можете индексатор списка и любой другой коллекции (кроме массива) получить по `ref`. Так как индексатор коллекции технически - это метод, возвращающий значение нужного типа, а не поле и не переменная. (индексатор массива - не метод, это компонент для вычисления смещения в памяти относительно начала данных, уможаемый на длину каждой ячейки данных в байтах, его можно использовать по `ref`)

Создайте перегрузку метода `Swap`. Кстати, называйте в C# методы с большой буквы, так код легче читать.

```cs
public static void Swap<T>(IList<T> list, int aIndex, int bIndex)
{
    T value = list[aIndex];
    list[aIndex] = list[bIndex];
    list[bIndex] = value;
}
```

Использовать можно так

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public int Index { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Index.ToString();
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>
    {
        new MyClass { Index = 1 },
        new MyClass { Index = 2 }
    };

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list));
    Swap(list, 0, 1);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```cs
1, 2
2, 1
```

В вашем случае будет выглядеть так

```cs
Swap(Parent0, Mutated[p].Pop(), Mutated[p].Pop());
```